# Browser detect contenteditable features

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, contenteditable

I realise browser detection is not generally a good idea, however as each browser has a different implementation of contenteditable, I need a way to separate out my fixes for each.

Specifically:

gecko and webkit require a `<br />` to be inserted at the end of empty paragraphs, otherwise they are automatically deleted.

ie and opera treat this `<br />` as an ordinary `<br />` and insert a newline.

I need a way to tell which browser or at least which of the implementations to use.

Please could you help me to find a method?

Thanks, Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I decided to go with quite an interesting solution to this: Use css browser prefixes to detect the browser.

for instance `if(elem.style["MozBorderRadius"] != undefined)` targets firefox1+ and the same can be done with WebkitBorderRadius.