# Detect if browser supports contentEditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497942/browser-detect-contenteditable-features), but the solution posted is browser sniffing, which I'm trying to avoid.

I need to make my website compatible with the iPad and perhaps newer Androids. I've been using an old version of the FCKEditor (now CK Editor) for my WYSIWYG editors, but that doesn't work on mobile, so I want to swap it out for a simple textarea with something like markdown, if it's not supported.

Supposedly it won't work because mobile devices tend not to support this `contentEditable` property, which means the on-screen keyboard won't pop up when you click on it.

How can I detect if the browser supports `contentEditable`? It's been suggested that I just check the div in question with something like `mydiv.contentElement === undefined` or something like that, but the div (if it's using one) is all built into the FCK Editor and buried somewhere in an iframe.

Isn't there another way to detect if a browser supports `contentEditable` in general?

---

Just tried this:

```
var contentEditableSupport = typeof $('<div contenteditable="true">')[0].contentEditable !== 'undefined';
```

Says "true" on my iPad...... I don't think it should.

**Edit:** It's returning "string" because all attributes are strings.... it's just reading the attribute. How else am I supposed to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help or not (no iOS here to test on), but the default value of `$('<div/>')[0].contentEditable` is `inherit`. What does iOS show?

Comment: @fudgey: Will have to check on Monday... I don't actually have an iPad. Just have one at work.

Comment: @fudgey: Couldn't check...got moved onto other things. No access to an iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the test I use and is also [used in Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/570). It will give false positives in iOS 4 (and possibly earlier) but unfortunately it's impossible to detect in those environments.

```
var contentEditableSupport = "contentEditable" in document.documentElement;
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this, as that's a fairly well known framework. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: Fair enough, although well-known frameworks are far from infallible.

Comment: Well, if I ever come back to this and discover that this solution doesn't work and find a better one, I'll steal your check-mark away ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could create an anonymous editable div, check it for contentEditable, then remove the div.

Comment: Similar approach to Modernizr (only Modernizr doesn't detect editables).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this by checking the default value of the `contentEditable` property rather than the presence or type.  The [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) indicates that the missing value default for `contentEditable` is "inherit", but in older browsers (e.g. Android/Gingerbread) the default value is "false".  Thanks to fudgey for the comment on the OP that pointed me in the right direction!

This test works for me:

```
var contentEditableSupport = $('<div/>')[0].contentEditable == 'inherit';
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for execCommand

```
if (document.execCommand) {
    ... browser supports contentEditable
} else {
    ... browser doesn't support contentEditable    
}
```

Comment: Testing for `document.execCommand()` is not the same thing as testing for `contenteditable`. For example, Firefox supported `document.execCommand()` for years before adding `contenteditable` support in version 3. In general it's better to test for the actual feature you're interesetd in.

Answer (score 0):

To check if any propery exits for a element. You can do this

```
var element = document.createElement('__ELEMENT__');
if ('__PROPERTY__' in element ) {
    // property supported in the browser
}
```

**or**

```
if ('__PROPERTY__' in document.createElement('__ELEMENT__') ) {
    // property supported in the browser
}
```

The below link contains it all.

1. https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/570
2. http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#contenteditable